# Acessar as propiedades de um array de objetos dentro de outro array?

Tags: react, axios, redux

Estou consumindo uma api de localidades no react e é obrigatorio usar o redux, tenho um button que manda uma ação passando uma sigla para pegar ela no reducer, com essa sigla eu faço uma requisiçao para buscar todas as cidades de um estado.

[imagemDoButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8dDh.png)

[imagemDoReducer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nANq.png)

Quando eu passo esse array para o state e mando para a home (onde eu vou renderizar os dados com um map, eu não consigo, pq eu recebo o array de objetos dentro de outro array.

[imagemOndeReceboOArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLyuo.png)

Alguma dica de como resolver?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1):

Existe um método do javascript que pode te ajudar nesse caso. Chama 'flat'.
No caso você só vai precisar fazer algo como:

```
cities.flat();
```

Fazendo isso ele vai tornar o Array[][] em Array[].
Mais detalhes aqui [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)